# Tkinter label only shows last value of for loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to include every solution of my function into a label one by one like this:

```
name1 value1
name2 value2
...
...
namei valuei
```

My code only prints `namei valuei` in the label in my Tkinter window.

```py
def evaluaterel(library,Model,InputArray):
    nrExp = len(InputArray)
    DBL2ARR = ctypes.c_double * nrExp
    outputs = DBL2ARR()
    for i in range(2,13):
        Name= outputName(Model,i)
        library.evalVBA(Model,InputArray,nrExp,i,outputs)
        for i in range(nrExp):
            Value = str(outputs[i])
            label['text']= str(Name)+ ' ' + str(Value)
```

How do I print every single value in the label?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
text = label.cget("text") + '\n' + str(Name)+ ' ' + str(Value)
label.configure(text=text)
```

for example:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
import random

wn=Tk()
wn.geometry("300x300")

mytext=Label(wn,bg="pink",width=30,height=200)
mytext.pack()

for i in range(10):
    text = mytext.cget("text") + '\n' + str(i)
    mytext.configure(text=text)


wn.mainloop()
```

output:

[image]